# API Rate Limits for IBM Cloudant

Tags: api, cloudant, rate-limiting

For using the IBM Cloudant database through Bluemix Service, REST APIs are available. The documentation does not mention anything about Rate limits on API usage. Are there any such limits, what error does the API throw if the limit is exceeded?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, there are rate limits based on the selected plan. Refer to this link for details https://console.ng.bluemix.net/catalog/services/cloudant-nosql-db.
Rejected API calls return HTTP code `429 (Too Many Requests)`

Comment: Thank you so much for your reply. The documentation describes plans based on data usage. If there are rate limits, how many API calls are allowed for each of the plans is not documented. Could you please share a link for that?

Comment: The [Cloudant page in the Bluemix catalog](https://console.ng.bluemix.net/catalog/services/cloudant-nosql-db) has this information. The Cloudant Lite plan includes 20 lookups/sec, 10 writes/sec, and 5 queries/sec. The Cloudant Standard plan includes 100 lookups/sec, 50 writes/sec, and 5 queries/sec.

Comment: What do we mean by lookups and queries? Does lookups mean get all documents and query search indexes, and queries means finding based on text/json indexes, views?

Comment: A lookup is a lookup of a single item by its key, e.g. retrieval of a document. All the examples you've listed (`_view`, `_all_docs`, `find` etc) count as queries.